# No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/AlertDialog' error after the latest android 3.2 sdk update

Tags: android

I ran into the following error after upgrading my `android sdk` to 3.2:

```
-resource-src:
 [echo] Generating R.java / Manifest.java from the resources...
 [aapt.exe] c:\jenkins\workspace\AndroidAppBranch2.0_conversion\res\values\themes.xml:11: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/AlertDialog'.
```

I didn't change anything in the code and the only thing that I did was upgraded the Android SDK to 3.2 this morning when the `SDK Manager` prompted me. I upgraded the `SDK` on another machine (stupid me...) and the same error showed up.

**Has anyone run into this?**

Comment: Here is a good solution: http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2011/08/new-to-android-more-style-restrictions.html

Answer (score 2):

AAPT is broken in 3.2
Only (discovered) workaround is replacing platform-tools with a previous version...

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/550fce9670530d9b/9b2b2aa389dce367?show_docid=9b2b2aa389dce367

Comment: Your answer rocks! After replacing the platform-tools, my build is working again. Thank!

Answer (score 0):

Latest info I could find, seems replacing with the previous version is not going to be a proper fix, nor will there be a change to current version:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/550fce9670530d9b/351daa9f65a7a09a?lnk=raot