# Styling the DatePicker

Tags: android

I have been trying very hard to style the text size and colour on android 3.2. When attempting to override the default style with

```
<item name="android:numberPickerInputTextStyle">@style/numberPickerInputText</item>
```

I always get this error:

```
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:numberPickerInputTextStyle'.
```

Why is this so? I am pretty sure I selected the correct style to override (dug it from the platform 13 API folder)

I looked in these places.. seems like it cant be helped!

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18659#c8

[No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/AlertDialog' error after the latest android 3.2 sdk update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738502/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-androidstyle-alertdialog-error)

This blog below said something about importing the styles into my application. How is it supposed to be done? examples?

http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2011/08/new-to-android-more-style-restrictions.html

Can someone please point me to the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty way.. apply it after you show the dialog. Not a good solution but it works.. still looking for other solutions :)

```
//Should'nt be here but well..
public static void changeDialogTextSize(Dialog dialog) {
    TextView tvMessage = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
    if (tvMessage != null)
    {
        tvMessage.setTextSize(25f);
        tvMessage.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }       
}
```